# How to handle Autolayout constraints while Pedictive Text is Enabled/Disabled on Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, keyboard-events

**This is how my UI is:**

- 2 TextFields, say tfA and tfB (tfA displays Predictive Text and tfB doesn't)
- A UIButton that stays right above the Keyboard (This button uses Autolayout and is constrained to the Bottom Layout Guide with value 0)

**Use Case where I see a problem:**
When I switch between the TextFields, since the Predictive text is enabled for tfA and not for tfB, I see a Glitch while Animating back and forth like this:

[image]

I'm thinking of somehow handling animation in `textFieldBeginEditing` Delegate method. Not sure of what I can do but any solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for Login suggestion doesn't make sense.

use following settings.

[image]

If you still want to use it. 
try add your button in inputAccessoryView

```
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 100))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    customView.addSubView(btnSignIn) // add you
    textFieldUsername.inputAccessoryView = customView
```

Comment: I know It doesn't make sense to have suggestion for Login but that's the requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add observer in your view controller for keybaord like this:

In `viewDidLoad()` method set observer

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame
        , object: nil)
```

and implement the method:

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification:Notification){
     //handle keyboard frame changes here
 }
```